# How to cancel snap mode programmatically?

Tags: c#, windows-8

I am a newer windows8 programmer.
and now I want to know how to cancel snap mode programmatically.
I know that we can't transit snap mode programmatically.

Comment: I have actually used TryUnsnap successfully to programmatically unsnap. So it is definitely allowed and supported :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you are in the snap mode, you can call the `ApplicationView.TryUnsnap()` method to attempt to unsnap. This returns a `Boolean` specifying whether the call was successful. ([MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.tryunsnap.aspx#Y0))

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be advised UI wise, simply create a page that has a button to return to the original full size.

Constraining the user to only one mode will make him/her think it's broken.